# How can i change the style of default dropdown sorting of products in woocommerce

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, css, woocommerce

[image]I was wondering is there any way to change the style of default dropdawn sorting of product(A-z,Sale) in woo-commerce  to any other style for eg :Tabs

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how much you need to modify it, but in wordpress you can generally override default styles of any plugin/theme/etc by using a custom CSS plugin.  In your browser, inspect the element you want to change to get it's class or id, then make a custom CSS rule to modify it.  While many plugins have some level of theme customization functionality, it is normally very limited and probably not enough to match your theme to your plugin very well.

Comment: No,overriding the css will not help me with this particular problem

Comment: I have added this tabs with css,But they are static

Comment: do you have a URL so I can see an example?  It's been awhile since I've done much customization to WooCommerce, but css overrides almost always work unless they are dynamically overriding the css with JavaScript.In most cases you just need increase your specificity to match that of the target rule ie: .myclass ul li {} instead of just li {} can effect which rule gets precedence.

Comment: Yes sure, http://135.a81.mwp.accessdomain.com/c/sex-toys/ (It is showing the default dropdawn at the bottom and my tabs which i made it static is above) That's  how i want my dropdawn to look like in tabs,But they are static

Comment: https://www.lovehoney.co.uk/sex-toys/vibrators/egg-vibrators/  (This is the refrence site i want to make the tab looks)

Comment: lol, I will need to help you with this after I get off of work. :D

Comment: So I took a quick look at this and it can be done in CSS.  set overflow hidden to the select element and display:block; float:left to you option tags.  You can probably figure out the rest

Comment: you will also need to set the height on the select to the same as your options and hide the border to prevent weird spacing.

Comment: I have made the changes.But i want to get rid off the sort by keyword in the front eg:sort by popularity to only popularity,Do you have any idea how to achieve that?

Comment: you could use javascript to replace the innertext